# How to compress the string using gzip and encode in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, gzip, encode

I'm trying to compress and encode my string using gGIP in python 2.7, I'm able to do that in Python 3 but I'm not getting same output in Python 2.7 version code:

**Python 3:**

```
import sys
import redis
import io import StringIO
import gzip

redisConn = redis.StrictRedis(host="127.0.0.1", port=6379, db=0)

myValue = "This is test data"
result = gzip.compress(myValue.encode())
redisConn.set("myKey", result)
```

**Python 2.7:**

```
import sys
import redis
import StringIO
import gzip

redisConn = redis.StrictRedis(host="127.0.0.1", port=6379, db=0)
myValue = "This is test data"
out = StringIO.StringIO()
gzip_s = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="w")
result = gzip_s.write(myValue.encode())
redisConn.set("myKey", result)
```

But Python 2.7 version code is breaking I'm getting an error:
'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Can someone please help what's the equivalent code of Python 2.7 - my Python 3 version is working as expected.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: try `gzip_s.write(myValue)`

Comment: Can you add the traceback to show where the error is occurring?

Comment: are you sure of `int` object has not attribute 'encode'? It's probably `str`, not `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2 doesn't make the distinction between strings and bytes (even if the gzip stream is open as binary like here). You can write strings in a binary stream without needing to encode it. It has some drawbacks but in your case just remove the `.encode()` call:

```
gzip_s.write(myValue)
```

for a Python 2/3 agnostic code, I would simply do:

```
if bytes is str:
   # python 2, no need to do anything
   pass
else:
   # python 3+: encode string as bytes
   myValue = myValue.encode()

gzip_s.write(myValue)
```

EDIT: since you seem to issue a command `redisConn.set("myKey", result)`, don't forget to call:

```
gzip_s.close()
```

before that, or it's not guaranteed that the file is fully flushed.

Comment: for `bytes is str` did you mean to use `isinstance`?

Comment: or just change myValue and use the same invocation of `gzip_s.write`.

Comment: nope, I mean compare classes python 2 defines `bytes` for some kind of limited compatibility, but `bytes` is the same class as `str`. test it on python 2 & 3. you'll get True & False.

Comment: @Aif change `myValue` by what?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i mean if python3 then myvalue = myvalue.encode() and that's all.

Comment: oh, that! yes. edited, you're right it saves some copied code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - If I try to do gzip_s.write(myValue) - its failing - it says Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream when i try to read the key from Java Redis client where as my Python 3 code insert and retrieve also as expected

Comment: @rubydeveloper see my update. You need to close the gzip stream before issuing a command. else file may not be flushed. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete working example for Python 2.7. Note that `gzip_s.write()` returns the number of bytes written, so your code is passing an int to `redisConn.set("myKey", result)`. Also, you probably *should* explicitly encode and decode the data to avoid unexpected encoding/decoding errors if you ever need to store non-ASCII data.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import redis
import StringIO
import gzip

redis_cxn = redis.StrictRedis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=0)

test_data = u'This is some test data with a non-ASCII character: ñ'
print 'Test data:\n    ', test_data

out_file = StringIO.StringIO()

gzip_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out_file, mode='wb')

# If you don't encode the data yourself, it will be implicitly encoded as
# ASCII.
gzip_file.write(test_data.encode('utf-8'))

gzip_file.close()

# Get the bytes written to the underlying file object
value = out_file.getvalue()

print 'Setting value in Redis'
redis_cxn.set('key', value)

print 'Getting value from Redis'
retrieved_value = redis_cxn.get('key')

assert retrieved_value == value

in_file = StringIO.StringIO()
in_file.write(retrieved_value)
in_file.seek(0)

gzip_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=in_file, mode='rb')
retrieved_data = gzip_file.read()
retrieved_data = retrieved_data.decode('utf-8')
gzip_file.close()

assert retrieved_data == test_data
print 'Data retrieved from Redis and unzippped:\n    ', test_data
```

Comment: If I try to do this - its failing - it says Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream when i try to read the key from Java Redis client where as my Python 3 code insert and retrieve also as expected

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example. IMO, you shouldn't just skip encoding/decoding on Pyton 2.7, because that often leads to unexpected errors down the line.